# How to autoupdate quiz question to newest version?

Tags: quiz

We have round about 200 quizzes with 5-10 questions. And most of the questions were updated by us. But we realized that quiz shows only the old versions.

Only solution so far is to check quiz by quiz and click updated to newest version question by question.

In settings I didn't find any possibility to auto switch to newest version as soon as the question got updated.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Of course, we can switch every question to newest version as soon as we update them. But what about all the aprox 1000/2000 questions in system that still run on old version instead of newest?

quiz.info: `version = "7.x-5.0-alpha8+14-dev"`

Comment: What version of quiz are you using?

Comment: quiz.info says `version = "7.x-5.0-alpha8+14-dev"`.

Comment: I think you may need to update and run update script and make sure manual revisioning turned off and it should work, there are many duplicates of this issues in the issue queue but on the current version with revisioning turned off it seems to be fixed.

Comment: But I've been wrong before :(

Comment: Thanks, that helped alot. Maybe you can post `manual revisioning turned off` as answer, so I can accept it as correct answer. Including the information about duplicates of this issue and maybe a link to drupal issue.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the issue queue its says that the update issues only happen when manual revisioning is enabled. You can find out more here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1652936
Also make sure to update to latest version and run update scripts.